# In a chain of project references a referenced dll is going missing from the output

Tags: .net

Using VS2017, Project A uses NHibernate and has a NuGet reference to Iesi.Collections.dll (which is used by NHibernate). Project A is referenced by Project B, and while B has no explicit reference to it the Iesi.Collections.dll still appears in Project B's bin\debug folder. Project B is referenced by Project C, now however the Iesi.Collections.dll does not appear in its bin\debug folder and while it compiles there's a resultant runtime error.

I've tried explicitly changing the Copy Local field on the reference to Iesi.Collections.dll in Project A to False and then back to True and verified it's added the True element in the csproj file, but this hasn't helped.

I've also tried removing and re-adding the reference in Project A using NuGet, which also hasn't helped.

I would expect Project C to include the Iesi.Collections.dll assembly in it's bin\debug output folder as this is a dependency of Project A and Project C should not need to know what assemblies to reference itself in order for A to work (separation of concerns).

Comment: What project types are all of these? If they're mixed .NET runtimes, they might not copy over or reference one another correctly. For example, .NET Core, .NET Standard, and .NET 4.8 are not all necessarily compatible with all Nuget packages. It depends on the Nuget package's target frameworks.

Comment: @CameronTinker they are all the .NET Framework 4.6.2 Class Library type.

Answer (score 0):

Following advice on other questions I declared an instance of a type within the Iesi.Collections.dll assembly without instantiating it in a class within Project A to minimise the memory usage and the dll now appears in Project C's compiled output. While it solves the problem I don't like this solution as Project A technically requires knowledge of the inner workings of Iesi.Collections.dll.